# Letting a thread run after main form closes and doesn't wait for thread to finish

Tags: multithreading, delphi

Is it possible to create a simple Thread, which runs a SQL statement, and then close the application but let that thread run untill it is finished (main form still closes normally - doesn't wait for thread to finish).

I'm upgrading an application which writes some test data to a log file and I want to bulk insert that log file into a database. Because there is a lot of data and the sql stored procedure which handles it takes a minute or two to complete I've made a thread which runs the stored procedure. This thread is run every so often during the lifetime of the app but now I want to implement so that after the user is finished with testing and closes the app, the rest of the data in the log that isn't on the server yet is synced. This way I can avoid checking logs of previous days if all data is synced.

If I use `waitfor` function, the whole application won't close untill the stored procedure is finished which is undesirable, because there is nothing the app has to do afterwards. The stored procedure handles all the errors so there is no need to handle errors in the app.

If I remember correctly this is something that is done a lot in linux, a procedure creates another procedure and then ends and the child proc is then orphaned, it is how demons are run. But I have no idea if this is even possible on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A process needs to stay alive until the thread completes. A thread exists in a process. Take away the process and the thread cannot endure.

What you can do is to wait for the thread after the UI has shut down. Put the code that waits for the thread in a method that runs after the UI has closed.

Or, if you want the UI process to terminate before the task completes, that task would have to live in a separate process. You would start a new process to perform the task. That's a lot easier in Unix-like systems which support `fork()`. Under Windows you'd need to find a way to get the data into the new process.

Comment: Ah I see I mixed up new threads and new processes. Getting data into the new process shouldn't be a problem at this stage since it is always a log file with todays date as it's name.